# How to remove a matching address on two different locations on google maps?

Tags: maps

I have been frustrated with this problem. My building address shows two different places on google maps and many delivery service companies are going to the wrong place.
The incorrect coordination of my building address, 11815 Misty Valley Drive, Houston, TX, 77066, is 29.967871308463753, -95.50322066053971. The correct one is 29.965073562937878, -95.5013219343926. I have also attached two pictures of the correct one and the wrong one. Can anyone please hlep me with this?
[image]
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Tell Google about the problem. After you do this, Google will probably correct the issue within a few weeks.

- Go to [www.google.com/maps/](http://www.google.com/maps/)
- Enter your address.
- When the wrong location pops up:
  Suggest an edit on (your address)